# Data loss with snapshots

Tags: zebra-savanna

Since snapshots will remove 0 value transactions to reduce data storage on nodes. So should I always send 1 IOTA when tracing data on my supply chain or what is the recommendation to avoid data loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation is to use a Chronicle Permanode so there is no need to send dummy transactions to keep the data permanently. Actually, after the Sandbox (based on IOTA’s devnet) phase the plan is to move to a production-ready service which will run within Zebranet, a “Child Tangle” Network devoted to Track & Trace applications and trusted data sharing, which will incorporate off-the-shelf Permanodes.

Comment: Even though one has to mention that this introduces a centralization, if you don't use your own permanodes.

Answer (score 0):

Nice development!
So, The Child network will grow with the history of track & trace data. On servers maintained by Zebranet or do companies still have to 'own' the hardware(off-the-shelf Permanodes)? This Zebra network is then hooked to the Tangle for immutability checks ect?

Regards,

Andre

Answer (score 0):

Our approach for the APIs and its underlying IOTA infrastructure is to be **flexible** on the infrastructure and deployment models. To this aim, Zebranet can incorporate Permanodes available to API clients, but we can also allow deploying customer's Permanodes connected to Zebranet, if it is required.